# BoxCars Java Program - Beginner. Weird Issue: Program doesn't run in the console but, it lists no errors in Eclipse Java

Tags: java

I wrote this code in Eclipse Java and for some reason, it doesn't run. It doesn't say it has any errors in it and no red marks appear anywhere in the code. I'm not sure what is wrong with it, please help.

Here is the description of what I needed to write: Design and implement a class called PairOfDice, composed of two six-sided Die objects. Create a driver class called BoxCars with a main method that rolls a PairOfDice object 1000 times, counting the number of boxcars (two sixes) that occur.

```
public class dieGames {

    public class PairOfDice {

       private int die1; 
       private int die2;

       public PairOfDice() {
           roll();
       }

       public void roll() {
          die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
          die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
       }

       public int getValueDie1() {
          return die1;
       }

       public int getValueDie2() {
          return die2;
       }

       public String toString() {
          return "Die 1: " + die1 + ", Die 2: " + die2;
       }
    }

    public class BoxCars
    {
       public void main(String[] args)
       {
          final int numRolls = 1000;
          int numBoxCars = 0;

          PairOfDice twoDice = new PairOfDice();

          for (int i = 0; i < numRolls; i++)
          {
             twoDice.roll();
             if (twoDice.die1 == 6 && twoDice.die2 == 6)
             {
                numBoxCars++;
             }
          }

          System.out.println("Number of Box Cars in " + numRolls +
                             " rolls is " + numBoxCars);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things that I can see here:

1. you never create an instance of your diceGames class
2. your main method is not static, which is required
3. your main method is inside another class definition, which is also never instantiated

a couple of adjustments to your code make it run fine (commented in the code below):

```
// this class remains unchanged, except for making the PairOfDice class static
// so that it's accessible to the main method
public class dieGames {

    public static class PairOfDice {

       private int die1; 
       private int die2;

       public PairOfDice() {
           roll();
       }

       public void roll() {
          die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
          die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
       }

       public int getValueDie1() {
          return die1;
       }

       public int getValueDie2() {
          return die2;
       }

       public String toString() {
          return "Die 1: " + die1 + ", Die 2: " + die2;
       }
    }


    // removed containing class, which was unnecessary
    // made main method static
    public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          // create an instance of the class
          dieGames game = new dieGames();  

          final int numRolls = 1000;
          int numBoxCars = 0;

          PairOfDice twoDice = new PairOfDice();

          for (int i = 0; i < numRolls; i++)
          {
             twoDice.roll();
             if (twoDice.die1 == 6 && twoDice.die2 == 6)
             {
                numBoxCars++;
             }
          }

          System.out.println("Number of Box Cars in " + numRolls +
                             " rolls is " + numBoxCars);

    }
}
```

From this, I get output of `Number of Box Cars in 1000 rolls is x`, where x is some value depending on the run.

If you want to meet the assignment as you post it, the "driver class" BoxCars can be a separate .java file containing the main method:

```
public class BoxCars {

    public static void main(String[] args)
       {

          final int numRolls = 1000;
          int numBoxCars = 0;

          PairOfDice twoDice = new PairOfDice();

          for (int i = 0; i < numRolls; i++)
          {
             twoDice.roll();
             if (twoDice.die1 == 6 && twoDice.die2 == 6)
             {
                numBoxCars++;
             }
          }

          System.out.println("Number of Box Cars in " + numRolls +
                             " rolls is " + numBoxCars);       
    }
}
```

In this case, you'll need to either make a getter method for die1 and die2, or make them public in the first file, which should now just be the PairOfDice class without the enclosing dieGames class. Notice that this main method now instantiates PairOfDice and not dieGames, since that class isn't required.

Comment: If I put the driver class (BoxCars) in a new Java Project how would I use my PairOfDice class in my BoxCars. Do I have to import it or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: They'll be two files in the same project. If they're in the same folder in Eclipse, they're able to access one another without needing an import statement (provided the relevant methods and attributes are public).

Comment: Do you know how I could implement two six-sided die objects into the PairOfDice class?

Comment: do you mean visually? with a GUI?

Comment: No, a die object like this, `private Die die2 = new Die();` 
How can I implement an object for two six-sided dies into the program?

Comment: maybe post a new question for this, explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping me with the other problem I was having